# ¿Cómo generar números aleatorios con srand y rand en C dentro de un rango de números determinado?

Tags: c, date

Transcribí un ejemplo de un programa para generar un lanzamiento de dados que estaba en el libro que uso. Lo pude entender pero hay una parte del código que me planteo una duda posterior.

- Con `srand(time(NULL));` puedo tomar la hora y convertirla en entero.
- Y con `dado = 1 + rand() % 6` puedo generar un número aleatorio entre 1 y 6 para la variable dado.

No entendí el razonamiento para llegar a la fórmula de dado pero funciono.

¿Cómo podría generar un número aleatorio en C con un rango diferente?

Ejemplo:

- Entre 1 y 9
- Entre 12 y 21

Gracias.

Comment: Si rand() te devuelve un entero, % es el modulo de rand, con lo cual va a dar un valor entre 0 y 5.. porque el resto hasta 6 es un valor asi.. y como vos queres algo entre 1 y 6, le sumas uno a eso y listo..

Comment: Análogamente, para generar un número entre 12 y 21, básicamente necesitas generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y 9 (ambos inclusive) y sumarlo a 12, por lo que podrías poner `12 + rand() % 10`. Para generar un número entre 1 y 9 sería `1 + rand() % 9`, etc.

Comment: Tengo que correrlo en frio en lápiz y papel o codificarlo y corrertlo para entender mejor lo que explicaste. Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Por un lado, la función [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) devuelve en cada llamada un número pseudo-aleatorio entre `0` y [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/RAND_MAX).

Por otro lado, el operador `%` devuelve el [resto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resto) de dividir el número a la izquierda contra el número de la derecha.

```
3478 % 26 = 20
```

[image]

---

Para simplificar mi explicación vamos a suponer por un momento que `RAND_MAX` es 19, estos serían los posibles valores de `rand() % 6`:

```
| rand() | resultado % 6 |
+--------+---------------+
|    0   |       0       |
|    1   |       1       |
|    2   |       2       |
|    3   |       3       |
|    4   |       4       |
|    5   |       5       |
|    6   |       0       |
|    7   |       1       |
|    8   |       2       |
|    9   |       3       |
|   10   |       4       |
|   11   |       5       |
|   12   |       0       |
|   13   |       1       |
|   14   |       2       |
|   15   |       3       |
|   16   |       4       |
|   17   |       5       |
|   18   |       0       |
|   19   |       1       |
```

Observa que todos los múltiplos de seis tienen residuo cero (como era de esperar) y que cíclicamente pasamos de cero a cinco por cada número entre cada múltiplo de seis. De cero a cinco hay seis números por lo que simula una tirada de dado, se le suma uno para modificar el rango de uno a seis.

Así pues, para simular una generación de números pseudo-aleatorios entre el número `A` y el número `B` (ambos incluidos), la siguiente fórmula se cumple:

```
(rand() % (B - A + 1)) + A
```

Por lo tanto números entre uno y seis `(rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1` → `(rand() % 6) + 1`, para números entre doce y veintiuno `(rand() % (21 - 12 + 1)) + 12` → `(rand() % 10) + 12`, etc...

---

Debes tener en cuenta que el truco de usar el operador `%` falsea la distribución aleatoria. Volviendo al ejemplo de `RAND_MAX = 20` verás que no todos los números se han generado la misma cantidad de veces:

```
| número generado por rand() % 6 | cantidad |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                0               |     4    |
|                1               |     4    |
|                2               |     3    |
|                3               |     3    |
|                4               |     3    |
|                5               |     3    |
```

Los números cero y uno son más probables que los números del dos al cinco.